# How to remove white space at the end of wordpress website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, dynamic

I can't get rid of the unwanted white space that added itself at the end of the website.

The link to the website is : http://www.authorwilliamjwarren.com/

I tried ,

1. deactivating plugins
2. html, body { height:100%}
3. reset to default CSS

But none of them didn't work for this.

I've checked most of other answers to the same problem, but nothing seem to fit my case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, 
Thank you !!

Comment: That site is beyond repair. The amount of junk in the page is epic. Remove all the junk first and then see if the issue is still there.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad, you can't expect us to analyze the code of an entire website and do the debug work. Maybe you could supply the relevant CSS, or something to go on?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not very good in coding and wordpress yet. can you pls tell me what do you mean by junk there? then I can remove them.

Comment: try removing the `div` with links which is right after the `<div id="logo">` or just set it `display:none`

Comment: @ShellFish I'm afraid that I don't know what is the relevant CSS for this. or what code or plugin or anything to occur this problem.

Comment: The junk is for example a huge list of invisible links to medicine in the page

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Thank you very much! That's the problem. I'm searching, php page for that code. If you know, pls let me know. Thanks again!!

Comment: @mplungjan ok. I'm searching where it come from. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stylesheet you have:

```
media="all"
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Replace it with the following:

```
media="all"
.navbar {
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

The position relative on the .navbar is causing your "whitespace" problem.

Comment: It really isnt. The off screen div containing hundreds of links of the problem.

Comment: whoops, missed that div!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of Header.php file. From where do you think those links come from? 
How to remove those links?

```html
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package dazzling
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<!-- favicon -->

<?php if ( of_get_option( 'custom_favicon' ) ) { ?>
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo of_get_option( 'custom_favicon' ); ?>" />
<?php } ?>

<!--[if IE]><?php if ( of_get_option( 'custom_favicon' ) ) { ?><link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo of_get_option( 'custom_favicon' ); ?>" /><?php } ?><![endif]-->

<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>

    <?php if( get_header_image() != '' ) : ?>

     <div id="logo">
      <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>"  height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"/></a>
     </div><!-- end of #logo -->

    <?php endif; // header image was removed ?>

    <?php if( !get_header_image() ) : ?>

     <div id="logo">
      <span class="site-name"><a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></span>
     </div><!-- end of #logo -->

    <?php endif; // header image was removed (again) ?>

          </div>
    <?php dazzling_header_menu(); ?>
      </div>
  </nav><!-- .site-navigation -->
```

Thank you!!